# Proof Techniques ( Soft Question )

Tags: soft-question

I've been googling around for books of methods of mathematical proofing, and I haven't had much luck finding anything reputable in book form. I do recall running by a few in a university library ( I no longer live near the particular one nor remember the library lookup system ), but names and titles escape me. Are there any books on the level of clarity of say, Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds" but for proof techniques?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Velleman's *How to Prove it: A structured approach.*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521675995)  It's excellent both as a text and as a reference.

Comment: Awesome reviews fits the bill. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, Doryan!

Answer (score 3):

Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* is a very terse, sophisticated book, so I'm not really sure what you're looking for. I am very fond of recommending Kevin Houston's *How to Think Like a Mathematician*. It's somewhat less formal, but more fun, than the typical introduction to higher mathematics book.

Comment: Equally awesome reviews. I'm probably going to grab both texts!